Use images as symbology for point features
I have a vector file that contains points having a name attribute that matches the name of traffic sign images I have stored locally. What I'm trying to do is to assign to each point its corresponding image. I'm not familiar with how the symbology works in QGIS, but I'm open to coding it. Any ideas?

This video shows how to achieve this (in German).

The answer is basically: Have your image paths as an attribute, then switch to raster symbol and use the image path for data defined override.
